# Submit form from external page (script security)

Tags: php, forms, security, post

I've a simple form for inserting contact data (PHP + MySQL) :

```
<form method="POST">
    <label>Name: <input type="text" name="name"></label>
    <label>Phone: <input type="text" name="phone"></label>
    <label>Email: <input type="text" name="email"></label>
    <input type="submit" name="addUser" value="Save">
</form>
```

Script is SQL Injection secured also data types are properly validated.

What I'm worried now is that someone could submit my form from external page + including some additional `<input>`s

1. Is it possible?
2. If so:

a) how to prevent such actions and secure the script?

b) Can additional inputs be included with external request?

c) If server uses SSL is it still vulnerable?

Comment: Ok Dagon. But there is nothing about SSL and including additional inputs to such external request.

Comment: SSL wont change anything and if your read the dupe that covers additional inputs.